# How to write performance test for kafka consumer java application?

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing, kafka-consumer-api, gatling

I am new to kafka. I have written a kafka consumer application using spring boot. This application consumes messages from kafka, processes it and stores in DB.

Now, I want to write performance test for the this consumer application. This test should tell me the performance of my consumer application like how much time it is taking to process messages under certain load.

I have written performance tests earlier using Gatling where we have endpoint. But in this application, I don't have any rest endpoint. So, if I get to know how to do performance tests for this application or any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to post messages to Kafka queue and measure how fast they're getting processed by your application, any tool suitable of doing this will fit.

1. For example [`kafka-console-producer` script](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_send) comes with each kafka distribution.
2. If you're good with Gatling you can use [Gatling-Kafka](https://github.com/mnogu/gatling-kafka) plugin.
3. There is also [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) plugin for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), this way you will not have to write a single line of code. Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for more details if needed.

Comment: I guess, above options will test performance of producer. I do not see how I can glue my consumer application with performance test and get performance data. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh` script packaged with Kafka. You can specify number of messages to read, number of processing threads and any of the usual [consumer configurations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs). The tool will output the amount of data consumed and the throughput among other metrics.